# Data table load failure

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to load a datatable, which I have done a million times, but I am getting this error that I don't know how to remediate.

```
Dim MainTA as New DRecordsTableAdapters.tblMainTableAdapter
Dim myTable as Datatable = MainTA.GetDuplicates
```

The error is generating while trying to load the datatable.
The error is:

> Input string was not in a correct format. Couldn't store  in RecordType Column. Expected type is Int16.

Where should I look to begin to fix this?

Comment: Is there an empty string (or blank space) where there should be a number, such as 0?

Comment: no. the GetDuplicates query connects a main table to a library table. the link is an ID field in both table, returning a text value. the query work in the dataset "configure" but not in the preview mode.  the query also works directly in the database

Comment: It looks like you have a type mismatch or some garbage in your raw data. Your table is expecting an `Int16` but the data cannot be implicitly converted. Can you run the query in `GetDuplicates` directly so you can see the dataset results?

Comment: I think it was broken somewhere deeper than the obvious places. The data is fine, i triple checked.  I ended up taking the queries and saving them in the database, recreated a table adapter that used those saved queries, corrected the code to point to the new table adapter and it worked as expected which makes me think something was "off" in the designer perhaps.

Comment: What almost certainly happened was that the `DataSet` was generated from the database, then the database schema was changed but the `DataSet` was not regenerated. There's a button on the toolbar in the Data Sources window to refresh the Data Source from the database, which should always be done after any schema changes.